# How to hide documents fields in a web CMS but not in android & iOS

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

Could you help me, provide me some tips and guide me to better secure my project ?

The project is a quizz with questions and answers.

- I have a web based CMS managed by an admin(custom claim) which connects to Firestore to CRUD data.
- Other users can connect a front end dashboard to see questions and answer them.
- There are 2 apps, iOS and android, users can also download the apps and answer questions.

In Firestore there is a collection "questions" with answers documents, each answer contain a field is_correct_answer (boolean)

How can I block users so that they won't be able to read the field is_correct_answer ?

If a clever user tries to inject the code below, he will see which is the correct answer of the question.

```
firebase.firestore()
          .collection("questions")
          .doc("question_1")
          .collection("answers")
          .doc("answer_1")
          .get().then(function(snap){

console.log(snap.data().is_correct_answer );
        })
```

Maybe it's a database related problem, a firestore rule, a wrong schema,... I don't really know. I just need to hide the correct answer to the user. I don't want them to find a path to see the corrects answers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the explanations provided by Frank van Puffelen and Jason Berryman, I finally found a solution to my problem:

I trigger an HTTP function which asks the admin SDK if the user exists. If true, I pass a JWT and log in the user. All requests made by this user are checked, thanks to the JWT back end. Doing this prevents the user from directly communicating with Firebase on the client side. Apps are encrypted and connection is HTTPS.

I don't know if this is safe and a "good practice", but it does work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore client-side SDKs always retrieve complete documents. There is no way to return (or restrict access to) a part of a document.

If you want certain fields to be inaccessible, you'll need to store those fields into a separate document. You can then control access to that specific document with security rules, and read the restricted document only for users who are supposed to have access to it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is there a way to protect those separate documents so that only an iOS or Android app could access it ? I'm not an app dev so I don't know at all. A web based cms seems a bad  idea if a user can access a database in a web browser and in an app?  If the user wants to see the correct answer in the app he would have to have a security flag, but having this security flag could let him to see the correct answers in the web based cms.

Comment: Access control in Firebase is based on user identity, not on the platform the user uses to access the data. That also wouldn't work, since any user can sign in to any platform (the APIs and configuration data are in each of your apps), so a malicious Android user could just write their own web code to read the other data.

Comment: Without any security rules, is it possible to decompile an iOs or android app to acces the database and manipulate it ?

Comment: All configuration data is in the app, since otherwise the app couldn't access the database. There is nothing that allows the database to only be accessed from a specific app/platform.

Comment: Ok, so if a malicious user tried to decompile the app he would be able to access Firestore if no Firestore rules were established ?          I won't bother you any longer after that ;)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to restrict access to the answers for users. Have the users submit an "answers" sheet when they complete the quiz/ each question and have a Cloud Function check the submitted answers, retrieve the private answers documents and update the submitted answer sheet, with a score.